# create rototable circle in android using Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

Guys I know How to draw circle in android..But what I need is using onTouch method to rotate that circle depending on the user hand movement on that circle. Please help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public class SampleView extends View {

    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    private Animation anim;

    public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    private void createAnimation(Canvas canvas) {
        anim = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
        anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        anim.setDuration(10000L);
        startAnimation(anim);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        int cx = getWidth()/2; // x-coordinate of center of the screen
        int cy = getHeight()/2; // y-coordinate of the center of the screen

        // Starts the animation to rotate the circle.
        if (anim == null)
            createAnimation(canvas);

        canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, 150, mPaint); // drawing the circle.
    }
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new SampleView(this));
}
}
```

Comment: @allSoAndroidProgrammers please give me hint guys very important

Answer (score 0):

First, we have to determine the angle between old and new position of circle (as below figure).

[image]

> cos a = uv / (|u|*|v|)

The simple equation may be

```
double tx = touch_x - center_x, ty = touch_y - center_y;
double t_length = Math.sqrt(tx*tx + ty*ty);
double angle = Math.acos(ty / t_length);
```

Then to rotate your Canvas. you can use the code

```
canvas.rotate(angle);
```

Or you can use another method as

```
public int touch_x,touch_y,cx,cy;
public float angle=0;
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    touch_x = (int)event.getX();
    touch_y = (int)event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    }
    //double tx = touch_x - cx, ty = touch_y - cy;
    // double t_length = Math.sqrt(tx*tx + ty*ty);
    //angle = (float) Math.acos(ty / t_length);
    double dx = touch_x - cx;
    // Minus to correct for coord re-mapping
    double dy = -touch_y - cy;
    double inRads = Math.atan2(dy,dx);
    // We need to map to coord system when 0 degree is at 3 O'clock, 270 at 12 O'clock
    if (inRads < 0)
        inRads = Math.abs(inRads);
    else
        inRads = 2*Math.PI - inRads;

    angle= (float) Math.toDegrees(inRads);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @user8340 ok I understood but where should I write this code

Comment: is der any listener or something where I can write your code

Comment: ok I got center_x and center_y I already have how m supposed to get touch_x and touch_y